# How can I debug this node / phantomjs issue further?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, phantomjs

I can run my script containing [portscanner.findAPortNotInUse()](https://github.com/baalexander/node-portscanner/blob/master/lib/portscanner.js#L41) locally(OSX) without error but when running on a bitnami EC2 instance I get:

```
events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: listen EADDRINUSE
    at errnoException (net.js:901:11)
    at Server._listen2 (net.js:1039:14)
    at listen (net.js:1061:10)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1127:5)
    at Object.module.exports.create (/home/bitnami/applications/tennistracker/node_modules/phantom/phantom.js:90:18)
    at /home/bitnami/applications/tennistracker/main.js:114:25
    at /home/bitnami/applications/tennistracker/node_modules/portscanner/lib/portscanner.js:136:7
    at /home/bitnami/applications/tennistracker/node_modules/portscanner/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:578:28
    at /home/bitnami/applications/tennistracker/node_modules/portscanner/lib/portscanner.js:119:9
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/bitnami/applications/tennistracker/node_modules/portscanner/lib/portscanner.js:96:5)
```

code is

```
var startPort = 50000;

portscanner.findAPortNotInUse(startPort, 50100, 'localhost', function(error, freeport) {
                console.log('freeport value: '+freeport);
            if(error) {
                console.log('portscanner error: '+error);
            }...
```

Additonal output:

```
freeport value: undefined
portscanner error: true
freeport value: undefined
portscanner error: true
```

I've disabled ufw on the server and also allowed the port range 50000 - 60000 in AWS. startPort is set to 50000. How can I debug this issue further? I've tried running `strace` but can't see anything obvious.

Comment: You cannot run a port scanner script on a AWS cloud its against there rules and regulation. They will suspend your account.

Comment: It is not really scanning ports. Its just looking for a local port which isn't already being used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was an issue with portscanner.js, in combination with my server setup (bitnami node stack on EC2). Editing the following line to set the host to '127.0.0.1' resolved the issue for me.

https://github.com/baalexander/node-portscanner/blob/master/lib/portscanner.js#L65

If anyone knows why, please post a further answer and I will accept. FWIW, my hosts file DOES already contain an entry pointing 127.0.0.1 to localhost